# Bluetooth comunication android

Tags: android, eclipse, bluetooth, andengine, multiplayer

I need to pass an Intent by bluetooth. Peviously I created the game and I save the caracteristics of the game in a class type singleton.

What I want to do is pass this information to the other device that I'm already connected and start de game that previously me or he/she created.

How can I send this information and the activity of the game?

I use andengine to make all the game.

Thanks!

Comment: I also want this information, so How to pass object between two connected devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think [this site](http://evilzone.org/java/%28android%29-three-ways-to-send-data-over-bluetooth/) may help you.  There are a few methods, but you want the last one mentioned in the OP.

```
public void sendFile(Uri uri, BluetoothSocket bs) throws IOException {
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));
        OutputStream os = bs.getOutputStream();
    try {
        int bufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        // we need to know how may bytes were read to write them to the byteBuffer
        int len = 0;
        while ((len = bis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } finally {
        bis.close();
        os.flush();
        os.close();
        bs.close();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.